# Is it possible to instantiate an object and pass it object initializer variables with Activator.CreateInstance?

Tags: c#

I need to be able to pass inline variables like so

```
new MyObject() { name = "John" }
```

But with an Activator. Something like

```
Activator.CreateInstance(myObjectType) { name = "John" }
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: Your syntax is called object initializer, it isn't an inline variable

Comment: Whoops, my bad. I'll edit the question

Comment: Object initializers are just syntactical sugar, just use a variable and set the properties

Comment: `Activator.CreateInstance` returns an `object` instance. You should cast it to `MyObject` first, then set `name`

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: Got it. Thanks guys!